# jasper report display odd or even pages sequentially

Tags: jasper-reports

How can i display jasper report page like `ODD: 1,3,5,7,9 .....` and `EVEN :2,4,6,8,10,12......`?

I tried to set print when expression in jasper.  I used `$V{PAGE_NUMBER} % 2 == 1`, but it just break the page 1 or 2.

How to print details in separate odd and even sequences?

I have tried this code:

```
jasperReport xmlns="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/xsd/jasperreport.xsd" name="null" language="groovy" pageWidth="595" pageHeight="842" columnWidth="555" leftMargin="20" rightMargin="20" topMargin="20" bottomMargin="20" uuid="927727f4-bbc3-4b13-bde4-00e4c9eff6b1">
<property name="ireport.zoom" value="1.0"/>
<property name="ireport.x" value="0"/>
<property name="ireport.y" value="0"/>
<queryString language="SQL">
    <![CDATA[Select * from area1;]]>
</queryString>
<field name="AREA_NAME" class="java.lang.String">
    <fieldDescription><![CDATA[]]></fieldDescription>
</field>
<background>
    <band splitType="Stretch"/>
</background>
<title>
    <band height="79" splitType="Stretch">
        <textField pattern="EEEEE dd MMMMM yyyy">
            <reportElement x="304" y="14" width="100" height="20" uuid="4260d472-d804-440a-9af6-1c3298d2f58f"/>
            <textElement>
                <font size="13" isBold="true" isUnderline="true" isStrikeThrough="false"/>
            </textElement>
            <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[new java.util.Date()]]></textFieldExpression>
        </textField>
    </band>
</title>
<pageHeader>
    <band height="35">
        <printWhenExpression><![CDATA[$V{PAGE_NUMBER} % 2 == 1]]></printWhenExpression>
    </band>
</pageHeader>
<columnHeader>
    <band height="40" splitType="Stretch">
        <printWhenExpression><![CDATA[$V{PAGE_NUMBER} % 2 == 1]]></printWhenExpression>
        <staticText>
            <reportElement x="23" y="2" width="100" height="20" uuid="5e8b28a3-3518-46e4-a62f-dfa585fc0c1b"/>
            <text><![CDATA[AREA_NAME]]></text>
        </staticText>
    </band>
</columnHeader>
<detail>
    <band height="136" splitType="Stretch">
        <printWhenExpression><![CDATA[$P{REPORT_PAGE}%2 == 0]]></printWhenExpression>
        <textField>
            <reportElement x="23" y="0" width="100" height="20" uuid="4b25e363-9dc8-47d4-8af4-3e6919e06020"/>
            <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{AREA_NAME}]]></textFieldExpression>
        </textField>
    </band>
</detail>
<columnFooter>
    <band height="45" splitType="Stretch"/>
</columnFooter>
<pageFooter>
    <band height="54" splitType="Stretch">
        <printWhenExpression><![CDATA[Boolean.valueOf( $V{PAGE_NUMBER}.intValue() % 2 == 1 )]]></printWhenExpression>
        <textField>
            <reportElement x="367" y="17" width="80" height="20" uuid="00d0dc34-6c9f-4265-83c8-b6778d349551"/>
            <textElement textAlignment="Right"/>
            <textFieldExpression><![CDATA["Page "+$V{PAGE_NUMBER}+" of"]]></textFieldExpression>
        </textField>
        <textField evaluationTime="Report">
            <reportElement x="459" y="17" width="40" height="20" uuid="fb935dbc-39fb-4589-b6fa-0af65a3c41b9"/>
            <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[" " + $V{PAGE_NUMBER}]]></textFieldExpression>
        </textField>
    </band>
</pageFooter>
<summary>
    <band height="42" splitType="Stretch"/>
</summary>
</jasperReport>
```

Comment: You can manage it from the query, what you want to show or hide using odd and even report page?

Comment: @user1791574  i need get the print using dot Matrix printer i want to print detail front and  back side of paper  like front 1,Back 2 ,Front 3 ,Back 4 .....